# Using the multi-dimension mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^p$ and $h:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$
>   be differentiable. Let $a, b\in U$ and suppose that
>   $L(a,b):=\{a+t(b-a)\ |\ t\in[0,1]\}$ lies in $U$, with $a\neq b.$

I have to show that \begin{equation}\frac{||h(b)-h(a)-Dh(\xi)\cdot(b-a)||}{||b-a||}\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^p{\sup_{x\in L(a,b)}}||\mathrm{grad}\ h_i(x)-\mathrm{grad}\ h_i(\xi)||\end{equation}
for all $\xi\in[a,b]$.

I got the feeling to introduce the function $g(x):=h(x)-Dh(\xi)\cdot x$. Because $h$ is differentiable, so is $g$. Now if we look at the $i$-th component, we see that there must exist an $\xi\in[a,b]$, such that $g'_i(\xi)(b_i-a_i)=g_i(b)-g_i(a)$.
I can see that $g_i(b)-g_i(a)=h_i(b)-h_i(a)-Dh_i(\xi)\cdot(b_i-a_i)$, so where that part from the fractional is from. But I don't know how to get any further.